# What causes pixelation, blurred graphics on a web banner?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, resolution

[image]

in the attached image, you can see pixlelation/distortion mainly on the red and blue text and red boxes. What causes this and how can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you've compressed it too much. As in, when you saved the image, you saved it with low quality... Assuming that they didn't look like that in Photoshop, before saving. The only distortion I can see is the text in the middle, the "RICHARD HARDIE..." text. Which I would say is not really distorted, it just looks a bit odd cause the letters are so close to each other. So the first issue you should be able to solve by saving it with better quality and the second issue you should be able to solve by adjusting the tracking to make the letter spacing a bit better.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will try increasing the quality. The richard hardie text is a logo that has been provided for use so that isn't my concern but on my screen, the red and blue 'scoop purchase' text is blotchy/distorted/low quality.

Comment: @Joonas please avoid answering questions in comments. As-is, your comment is good enough to be an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems you see are [compression artifacts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compression_artifact). If you want to make them less visible apply less JPEG compression on your Image, this in turn will make the banner larger in size.

[image][image]

**Image 1-2**: 2 compressed JPG images, the one on the left has more compression (25) that the one on the right (90). But the less compressed image is more than 4 times larger in file size.

Please note that your image may not be optimal for JPEG compression. All other elements, except the car, would benefit much more form a PNG/GIF compression.